Does PowerShell save a persistent history of all commands/output when PSReadLine isn't installed, and if so where is this history stored?
Does PowerShell save a persistent history of all commands/output when PSReadLine isn't installed, and if so where is this history stored?

@Destroy666 Yes I am aware of Get-History for getting session history but i need history of past sessions as well and all i can find is using the Get-PSReadlineOption cmdlet

Can you edit the PowerShell profile at leat or is that a no too?

at least that i can do

The default path is %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt if that's what you're asking -- but that path won't exist if PSReadLine has never been used in the first place.  Is your question "Does PowerShell save a persistent history of all commands/output when PSReadLine isn't installed, and if so where is this history stored?"

@Paulπ yes. exactly that's my question

The short answer is no, not natively.

To quote from PowerShell's about_History help documentation:

PowerShell has two different history providers: the built-in history
and the history managed by the PSReadLine module.

Using the PSReadLine history
The PSReadLine history tracks the commands used in all PowerShell
sessions. The history is written to a central file per host. That
history file is available to all sessions and contains all past
history. The history is not deleted when the session ends. Also, that
history cannot be managed by the *-History cmdlets. For more information, see about_PSReadLine.
Using the built-in session history
The built-in history only tracks
the commands used in the current session. The history is not available
to other sessions and is deleted when the session ends.



Cmdlet
Alias
Description




Get-History
h
Gets the command history.


Invoke-History
r
Runs a command in the command history.


Add-History

Adds a command to the command history.


Clear-History
clhy
Deletes commands from the command history.





PSReadLine History

(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath will retrieve the history file path of the current PowerShell host.
PSReadLine's stores persistent history files in the default directory %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\

ConsoleHost_history.txt
Visual Studio Code Host_history.txt
etc




This is not supported and obviously the best solution is to contact whoever had the brilliant idea of not including PSReadLine and persuade them to change their mind.
But if you have access to editing $PROFILE file, workarounds are possible:

Add automatic log file appending of Get-History entries when the shell exit event fires:

Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent -Action {
  (Get-History).CommandLine | Add-Content -Path "C:\Some\Path\To\log.txt"
}

Of course this won't work when PowerShell doesn't exit properly.

Write your own handling of reading the line, which is far from trivial, it'd be essentially rewriting part of PSReadLine in a nonsensical way. Good luck with that.

